# How does TypeScript infer element type for array literals?

Tags: arrays, typescript, type-inference, literals

In particular, why this code compiles (with --noImplicitAny)

```
function x() {
    const c = [];
    c.push({});
    c.indexOf({});
    return c;
}
```

while, this doesn't:

```
function x() {
    const c = [];
    c.indexOf({});
    c.push({});
    return c;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Both compiles with me, does it print out an error? Give us more information

Comment: @TareqEl-Masri, are you sure you enabled --noImplicitAny?

Comment: Please use the `Share` button to get a URL to the TypeScript playground with this code in it. That way we can all reproduce it easily.

Comment: `push` helps determine the type of element that is in the array; `indexOf` doesn't.

Comment: To determine the type of the array you can do it this way `const c: object[] = []`

Comment: @HereticMonkey, share does not copy compiler settings.

Comment: and thanks, captains xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behavior see this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23192). The function described there is similar to yours, the question being why no error is raised with `noImplicitAny` turned on:

```
function foo() {
  const x = []
  x.push(3)
  return x
}
```

> The type of the array is inferred to be an "evolving array" type. it then becomes `number` after the first `x.push`. foo should be returning `number []`.
>   If the type of `x` is witnessed before control flow can determine its type, and error is produced. e.g.:

```
function foo() {
  const x = []
  x.push(3)
  return x;

  function f() { 
    x; // error, x is `any`.
  }
}
```

So in your case, `indexOf` witnesses the type of the array before a type can be determined and an error is raised. If `indexOf` is called after `push` the type is determined and no error is raised.

Comment: Bonus question: is using only 'x.push(value), x.unshift(value) or x[n] = value' (and not indexOf(), etc) to evolve the array type somehow hardcoded into the compiler or it is defined somehow in one of d.ts files?